# Twig : Get value of the entity attached to the form in twig view Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I would like to access to the values of the entity I attached to my form in my TWIG view.

The form is created this way :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SuperForm(), $entity);
```

In the twig view if I display the `{{ dump(form.vars.value) }}` I have this :

```
Zone {#1000 ▼
#name: "First book zone"
 -book: Book {#538 ▶}
 -location: "inside"
 -priority: 5
 -live: true
 -BooksGroups: PersistentCollection {#1003 ▶}
 -hasGroups: true
 #slug: "sdds"
 #id: 2
 #createdAt: DateTime {#999 ▶}
 #updatedAt: null
 #owner: null
 #updateUser: null
}
```

EDIT:

However, when I try to access the value through this method, I can't :

```
{{ form.vars.value.name }}

Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null   variable
```

The curious thing is that, when I do it with de default method, I have no problem and the real value is displayed :

```
{{ form.vars.value.name|default('Default name') }}

Displayed: 'First book zone'
```

This is maybe a workaround for the strings and the integers, but how can I do for the Collections and the arrays ?

Comment: Yes, name is inside Zone. I tried, and I have the same result : Impossible to access an attribute ("Zone") on a null variable with this `dump(form.vars.value.Zone)`

Comment: Still the same result. I have read that it can come from the fact that the properties are private, but still how can I access them ?

Comment: The private|protected is not the problem, because you will never set your attributs public (or in some exceptional cases).
I have for example:
    `class Zone { 
        private $name;

        getName(){ return $this->name; }
    }`

Plus, I tried to put it public and it didn't change anything.

Comment: You already have the access to the entity in your controller right? If yes just pass it along the twig view in the array and you have access to all the variables.

Comment: Its in a Custom Form Type in a Collection which is also in a Collection, so it's not that easy. But I finally used the form.value.name|default('qwe') workaround... But if someone know why the normal way doest not work but this one does, I will be glad to hear !

Comment: @Djagu, you saved my day! Thanks! Have you ever got an explanation about we need your trick?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is needed because you are probably set `allow_add` option inside your collection type. So this is why first null comes from the `prototype` of the collection, since there aren't any values set in the prototype. Prototype is a special field which isn't rendered directly in Twig. This is why you have to set default value for `prototype` or set `allow_add` to `false` in your collection.

Comment: you should add the `form.value.name|default('')` in your answer to make it complete, in the cases we need to set `allow_add` to `true`